# Why are my images from my Canon EOS 6D randomly rotated 90 degrees

Tags: canon, canon-6d, image-stacking, rotation

I've shot a photo stack of tens of photos today using a steady tripod. However, in my results, some of my photos are randomly rotated incorrectly. It's both in camera and in Bridge and anywhere else. Here is a screenshot from Bridge:

[image]

The Camera/Tripod did not move even a tiny bit between these shots. I always take astrophotography stacks with the same equipment but this is the first time I've ever encountered such issue. I think I will rotate them manually selectively, but I want to understand why I'm facing this issue in the first place.

Comment: What was the camera's orientation while taking this stack? Was it aimed close to zenith?

Comment: @scottbb nope, that was also my first thought. it wasn't pointed towards zenith or it wasn't in any angle that may be at the border of horizontal/vertical orientation boundary. it was just tilted (rolled) about a maximum of 15 degrees (even less) and that's it.

Comment: It must be gravitational waves from the impending alien invasion.

Comment: What is the setting selected under *Setup 1 (Yellow)--> Auto Rotate*?

Comment: @MichaelClark my camera is not with me now but it's the default setting (never changed it since I've bought it). I'm also on latest firmware + ML.

Comment: Just a note, don't manually select your images, do a smart collection for image width then rotate those images.   Much faster. Hope that helps someone. Happy developing, https://twitter.com/cliffclof/status/796228184408608768

Comment: @cliffclof uhm.. I've never used Lightroom in my life. I hope there is a Photoshop/Bridge equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it sounds as if the gravity sensor that determines orientation is faulty. If this is the case, the camera will need repair to resolve your issue.

In Canon cameras, I believe that sensor is in the viewfinder prism housing. The sensor could be dirty, or it's possible it (or some other component in the camera) has gotten magnetized, causing it to flip out sometimes when the mirror flips up. (That's a long shot, but it's possible.)

Comment: Interesting as this problem never happened again, before or after. Weird, maybe something was causing interference.

Comment: Well since it never happened again, I would say it was something interfering. Possibly a magnetic field from something around the camera (gravity sensors can possibly be quite sensitive sometimes). Without an intensive test environment, it's just conjecture of course, but I'd say it was something like that.