# How to fix rotation orientation of multiple images in a Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, rotation, selection

**How can I rotate multiple images of vertical orientation in Lightroom that are scattered in a timelapse collection?**

if I have multiple images from my camera in a sequence that are rotated incorrectly from the camera how can I fix them?

For example if I took a lot of images like *Can Poyrazoğlu* did here: [Why are my images from my Canon EOS 6D randomly rotated 90 degrees](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/80091/why-are-my-images-from-my-canon-eos-6d-randomly-rotated-90-degrees)

**How can I fix only the ones that are rotated the wrong way quickly in Lightroom?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Lightroom filter bar, you can filter by aspect ratio. Select "Portrait" or "Landscape", depending on which images you want to change, then select all photos displayed (Ctrl-A) and rotate them.

Comment: Really!?  That is awesome, i looked around for that forever and couldn't find it.  I'll check it out.

Comment: All this time, I didn't even know you could drop down and change those filters, i just thought you were stuck with what they gave you, oops.

Answer (score 0):

**Use smart collections to select images of a certain height or width, rotate those images.**

To select only certain images from a specific image size camera you can use two constraints as shown below.

1. The height is above 5001 pixels
2. The Width is below 5000 pixels

This selects images from only one size type and one orientation you have in your collection if using multiple camera resolutions. (adjust the values to match your min & max image width and heights)

***Note: Post cropped images will be included in the search, be careful to do a visual inspection before rotating a large selection of photos***

Happy Developing.

[image: rotate multiple images in Lighroom quickly with smart collections]

Comment: If the OP only has 1 camera, all of them will have X-Y or Y-X pixel dimensions. To the eye, it's obvious which ones are not rotated correctly, but how does your suggestion determine that?

Comment: What about doing the actual rotation fix as a batch?

Comment: Both great points.   I should change the wording to remove batch, it is more of a selection.  The selection works for both 1 camera or multiple cameras.  In my case Lightroom has 3840 x 5760 images, and 5792 x 8688 images of vertical orientation.  With the constraint of selecting the height above 5759, and the width less than 3841 only the images from camera 1 were selected in the vertical orientation.   It saves time if you have shot multiple photos that were suppose to be horizontal orientation and the camera automatically rotated them wrong. (time lapse..)